# Making a Single field editable in a Databound Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm looking to make the MAC column editable because this is a registration application and this will allow users to update their registrations. I am binding data from a SQL database already and that works fine. I'm just not sure how to get the current MAC to bind and still be able to be editted. Any help would be appreciated, I've posted my asp.net (target framework of 4.5) code below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataDisplay" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" Height="78px" Width="727px" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="DataDisplay_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="DataDisplay_RowDeleting"
        OnRowEditing="DataDisplay_RowEditing" style="margin-right: 0px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Device" DataField="Device" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MAC Address" DataField="MAC Address" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Area" DataField="Area" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Registered" DataField="Date Registered" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the "MAC Address" BoundField with a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MAC Address" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMacAddress" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MAC Address") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMacAddress" Text='<%#Bind("[Mac Address]") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**EDIT:**

Rest of the fields should have ItemTemplate only, like this one:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Device" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDevice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Device") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**BTW-** spaces in Data Field Names is not a good idea!